# Bitbake create cmake recipe from local sources

Tags: cmake, yocto, bitbake

I'm trying to build a helloworld package example with a cmake recipe. My problem is bitbake give me an error because it can't find CMakeLists.txt in the /tmp/work/core2-64-poky-linux/helloworld/0.1-r0 folder.

The error :

```
helloworld-0.1-r0 do_configure: Execution of '/path-to-tmp/tmp/work/core2-64-poky-linux/helloworld/0.1-r0/temp/run.do_configure.28001' failed with exit code 1:
CMake Error: The source directory "/path-to-tmp/tmp/work/core2-64-poky-linux/helloworld/0.1-r0/files" does not appear to contain CMakeLists.txt.
```

My package is in my layer meta-mylayer/recipes-core/helloworld :

```
meta-mylayer/
├── conf
│   └── layer.conf
├── COPYING.MIT
├── README
└── recipes-core
    └── helloworld
        ├── files
        │   ├── CMakeLists.txt
        │   └── main_helloworld.c
        └── helloworld_0.1.bb
```

My CMakeLists.txt :

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.4)

project(helloworld)
file(GLOB_RECURSE files/*.c)

add_executable(app ${src_files})

install(TARGETS helloworld DESTINATION bin)
```

My helloworld_0.1.bb :

```
PN="helloworld"
PV="0.1"
P="${PN}-${PV}"
DESCRIPTION="This is my package helloworld"
LICENSE="CLOSED"
FILESEXTRAPATHS_prepend:="${THISDIR}/${PN}:"
RDEPENDS_${PN}+=""
DEPENDS+=""
DEPENDS+="cmake"

SRC_URI+="file://CMakeLists.txt file://main_helloworld.c"

S="${WORKDIR}/files"

inherit pkgconfig cmake
```

I can't find my files in /path-to-tmp/tmp/work/core2-64-poky-linux/helloworld/0.1-r0/*

Why files are not copied? I'm using yocto Dunfell.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have files in `SRC_URI` they are installed in `${WORKDIR}`.

The following recipe will do the trick:

```
DESCRIPTION="This is my package helloworld"
LICENSE="CLOSED"

SRC_URI+="file://CMakeLists.txt file://main_helloworld.c"

S="${WORKDIR}"

inherit pkgconfig cmake
```

Also, your `CMakeLists.txt` should not find files in `files` directory.

`S` is set to `${WORKDIR}` because this is where the files from the `file://` fetcher are put by default.

`DEPENDS` already has cmake-native in it from the cmake bbclass you inherited. You don't need to depends on cmake, because you depends on cmake-native (you need to **execute** cmake at build time, you don't need cmake headers or sources).

The `FILESEXTRAPATHS` that was added is already by default used by bitbake (and it's also not matching your directory layout).

`PN` and `PV` are gotten from the filename of the bb recipe, no need to set them again.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply, that solve my problem !